# Building a bilingual XML Schema

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I'm currently able to generate pretty good XML Schemas, but I would like to change my generator a little to be able to have a bilingual XML Document at the end. (The min and max occurrences parameters are normally managed)

I was thinking about changing this :

```
<xs:element name="root">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="my:Elem1" />
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Elem1" type="xs:string" />
```

to this :

```
<xs:element name="root">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="my:Elem1" />
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Elem1">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element ref="my:Elem1Eng" />
         <xs:element ref="my:Elem1Fra" />
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Elem1Eng" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Elem1Fra" type="xs:string" />
```

The only think I don't like with this is sometimes I generate XML Schemas that can have more than 50 element in it, so it's going to be 50 more complexType and 100 more elements to manage.

The goal here is to generate XSLT Files based on those XSD (already done this) but instead of having just an input for only one language, I would create a little table with two columns.

So instead of this :

```
Elem 1 english Name : __________(Elem 1 English Value)__________
```

It'd look like this :

```
| Element 1 English Name  |  Element 1 French Name |
+-------------------------+------------------------+
| Element 1 English Value | Element 1 French Value |
|    For user to enter    |    For user to enter   |
```

But when I have only one field, it seemed like I cannot duplicate the same field for a different value (even if it's in another language).

Do you guys have any more "efficient" way to produce a XML Schema that will allow a XML Document to be bilingual and by the same way allowing me to create my XSLT file this way ?